# Copy data from specified sheet of opened workbook and paste it to another specified sheet of closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I would like to copy data from aspecified sheet in an opened workbook to another specified sheet in a closed workbook.
I have a code like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Form Marketing Calendar1.xlsm").Worksheets("Form Single")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("Database Marketing Calendar.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
    'Offset property moves down 1 row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    wsCopy.Range("B22:AF25").Copy
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    wsCopy.Range("B26:AF30").Copy
    wsDest.Range("G" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    Selection.ClearContents
    wsDest.Parent.Close True

End Sub
```

Actually, it copied the data, but it has to open the destination file first then close it automatically.

It also only copies the first data (this: `wsCopy.Range("B22:AF25").Copy`), but the second data didn't copy (that: `wsCopy.Range("B26:AF30").Copy`).

Comment: Your code looks good and it copies everything but... `Selection.ClearContents` is erasing the last data copied, so delete that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRowB As Long
    Dim lDestLastRowG As Long

    'It is not possible to get data from a workbook without openning it, but this is the closest
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False 'won't show any changes on your screen
        .Visible = Flase 'will hide Excel. CAUTION: if the macro fails make sure to change this back to True
    End With

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Form Marketing Calendar1.xlsm").Worksheets("Form Single")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open("Database Marketing Calendar.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
    'Offset property moves down 1 row
    With wsDest 'with allows you to refer to the variable without writting it
        lDestLastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'You can use also +1 since it's a number
        'you are not copying the same amount of rows, so maybe the data won't be on the same row on both columns
        lDestLastRowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    wsCopy.Range("B22:AF25").Copy
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRowB).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    wsCopy.Range("B26:AF30").Copy
    wsDest.Range("G" & lDestLastRowG).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    'when you manually copy and paste you will see that the paste range gets selected. This line erases selected content so this is deleting it
    'Selection.ClearContents
    wsDest.Parent.Close True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanx mr.damian. I've got the solution from your answer